# Web Service returned error : Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, silverlight-4.0

The web service i am using returned web exception. Service is called from Silverlight application. Basically i am trying to convert eps file into png . On localhost everything is working well but when i deployed on web server i am getting this error. 
Silverlight Code is --

```
  private void btnUploadImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string fileextn = string.Empty;
            OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    string fileExtension = openDialog.File.Extension.ToString();
                    if (fileExtension.Contains("jpeg") || fileExtension.Contains("jpg") || fileExtension.Contains("png") || fileExtension.Contains("tif") || fileExtension.Contains("tiff") || fileExtension.Contains("bmp") || fileExtension.Contains("gif"))
                    {

                        using (Stream stream = openDialog.File.OpenRead())
                        {
                            HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("showProcessingAndBlockUI");
                            // Don't allow really big files (more than 2 MB).
                            if (stream.Length < 5 * 1024 * 1025)
                            {
                                MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream();
                                byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
                                stream.Position = 0;
                                stream.Read(data, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                                tempStream.Write(data, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                                stream.Close();
                                ProductConfiguratorServiceClient pcs = new ProductConfiguratorServiceClient();
                                string virtualpath = HelperClass.GetVirtual();
                                pcs.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(virtualpath + "/Services/ProductConfiguratorService.svc/basic");
                                pcs.GetFormattedImageCompleted += new EventHandler<GetFormattedImageCompletedEventArgs>(pcs_GetFormattedImageCompleted);
                                pcs.GetFormattedImageAsync(data);
                                pcs.CloseAsync();
                                tempStream.Close();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Files must be less than 5 MB.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (openDialog.File.Extension.Contains("eps"))
                    {
                        HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("showProcessingAndBlockUI");
                        using (Stream stream = openDialog.File.OpenRead())
                        {
                            if (stream.Length < 5 * 1024 * 1025)
                            {
                                MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream();
                                byte[] data = new byte[stream.Length];
                                stream.Position = 0;
                                stream.Read(data, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                                tempStream.Write(data, 0, (int)stream.Length);
                                stream.Close();
                                ProductConfiguratorServiceClient pcs = new ProductConfiguratorServiceClient();
                                string virtualpath = HelperClass.GetVirtual();
                                pcs.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(virtualpath +                                                                                              "/Services/ProductConfiguratorService.svc/basic");
                                pcs.GetEpsFileIntoPngCompleted += new EventHandler<GetEpsFileIntoPngCompletedEventArgs>(pcs_GetEpsFileIntoPngCompleted);
                                pcs.GetEpsFileIntoPngAsync(data);
                                tempStream.Close();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Files must be less than 5 MB.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please Check the Image Format.");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("hideBlockUI");
                    MessageBox.Show("Somr Error Occured, Please Try Again Later .");
                }
            }

        }

        void pcs_GetEpsFileIntoPngCompleted(object sender, GetEpsFileIntoPngCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
                busi.CurrentlySelectedOverlayImage.UploadedImageStream = e.Result;
                busi.CurrentlySelectedOverlayImage.ImageFileType = "png";
                RefreshStatus();
                busi.CurrentlySelectedOverlayImageChanged = true;
                HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("hideBlockUI");
        }

        void pcs_GetFormattedImageCompleted(object sender, GetFormattedImageCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.Error != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    busi.CurrentlySelectedOverlayImage.UploadedImageStream = e.Result;
                    busi.CurrentlySelectedOverlayImage.ImageFileType = "jpeg";
                    RefreshStatus();
                    busi.CurrentlySelectedOverlayImageChanged = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Error is at `System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest`.

Please assist me whether what kind of problem is this?

Answer (score 0):

It could have something to do with this line.

```
pcs.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(virtualpath +
```

You are missing the rest of it.
Pretty sure this is a compile error though.

So either this error is getting eaten and the generic one is popping up or you have some other issue along with this.

Comment: As you can see i have provided complete address. So should i do for this?

Comment: The code you have listed above has a compile error in it. There is no question. Its inside this conditional else if (openDialog.File.Extension.Contains("eps"))

Comment: Then how it is possible that it is running successfully over localhost?? I am confused with this, if possible then please provide a way to rectify this problem.

Comment: Perhaps you're running an old build OR you posted broke code but you are running good code OR the code on your local machine is different that the production code.... The list goes on. I am telling you that is a syntax error though.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will go through with this considering your opinion to sort out the problem.

Comment: C# Language Fundamentals (O'Reilly) - In C#, a complete program instruction is called a statement and each statement ends with a semicolon (;). Forgetting a semicolon is a very common mistake for novice programmers, but Visual Studio will catch you if you do it. Programs consist of sequences of statements, such as the following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596521066-01-03.aspx

Comment: I am unable to get you with semicolon thing as i have end each statement with semicolon.